# Unexpected Compiler warning with Generic Types and a Static member

Tags: generics, f#

I wanted to create my own list type `CountedList<'T>` that will have a normal F# list in it along with the count of the # elements in the list (so I don't have to traverse the whole list to get the # of elements).

This was my attempt:

```
type CountedList<'T> = {List: 'T list; Count: int}
                        static member Empty<'a> () = {List=List.empty<'a>; Count=0}
                        member this.AddOne(element) = {this with List=element::this.List; Count=this.Count + 1}
```

The idea is to start with a CountList.Empty of a certain type and then add an element through the AddOne method.

However, when I try to create the empty list with this:

```
let emptyDoubleList = CountedList.Empty<double>()
```

I  get the following warning:

```
The instantiation of the generic type 'CountedList' is missing and can't be inferred from the arguments or return type of this member. Consider providing a type instantiation when accessing this type, e.g. 'CountedList<_>'.
```

Yet doing it directly like this:

```
let directEmptyDoubleList = {List=List.empty<double>; Count=0}
```

does **not** give the warning.

Why do I get this warning? Shouldn't the compiler be able to realize that it is a CountedList? Also, any suggestions for how I can improve my CountedList implementation would be appreciated as well.

Here's the full code sample:

```
type CountedList<'T> = {List: 'T list; Count: int}
                            static member Empty<'a> () = {List=List.empty<'a>; Count=0}
                            member this.AddOne(element) = {this with List=element::this.List; Count=this.Count + 1}

let emptyDoubleList = CountedList.Empty<double>()   //Why does this give me a warning??

let directEmptyDoubleList = {List=List.empty<double>; Count=0}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the type argument to the `Empty<_>` method doesn't have to match the type argument to the `CountedList<_>` class.  So `CountedList<string>.Empty<double>()` is a valid method call that will return a `CountedList<double>`, and the compiler has no way to determine whether that's what you wanted.

You probably want to make `Empty` a non-generic method, and use `List.empty<'T>` in its body (which you'd then call like `CountedList<double>.Empty()`, or just `CountedList.Empty()` in contexts where the type's generic argument could be inferred by the compiler).  Alternatively, you might want to create a companion `CountedList` module and create a generic `empty` function in it, and remove the `Empty<_>` method from your class.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler doesn't realize that the type for `CountedList` in this example doesn't matter and only the type in the `Empty`command does. Thanks for the explanation.